# Unsuccessfully calling a function defined in JS file 2 from a function in JS file 1 AFTER the page has loaded/on-click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two Javascript files, that I will significantly streamline to simplify the issue in hand.

`form.js`

```
function open_action_dialog(){
   // code to open the dialog..

   // If [Return] is pressed when focus is on the #action field, call the action confirmation function defined in the second javascript file.
   $('#action').keypress(function(e){
      var fn_name = "action_confirm";
      if(e.which == 13)
         window[fn_name]();
   });
}
```

`blog.form.js`

```
$(function (){
   $("#dialog_action_open").click(function() { 
       open_action_dialog(); 
   });

   function action_confirm(){
     alert('action confirmed');
     return;
   }
});
```

So on my page I have a button with id `dialog_action_open` when clicked opens the action dialog; this is a function from the second file successfully calling a function from the first file.

Inside the dialog, there's an input text field with id `action` where I've set it so that if the user presses `[Return]` when their cursor is focused on the field, it should call the `action_confirm()` function defined in the second file. It does pickup the keypress event, but does not call the function from the second file; inside Google's code inspector, the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'action_confirm' of object [object Window] is not a function

So, my question is what do I need to do to be able to successfully call the function from the second file from inside a function in the first file? Keeping in mind, I'm aware you can't immediately call a function defined later. But, even though my action_confirm() function is defined after the function calling it from the first file, isn't this technicality moot considering the call is occurring AFTER the page has loaded, and more specifically AFTER a click event on the page?

I would appreciate being enlightened.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function you're trying to call is wrapped in another function, it's invisible to the function in your other JS.

You could remove `$(function (){` (and it's closing `});` )

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to have made any difference?

Comment: Actually, it did!! My mistake. Thanks very much.